# Can I save the information of the data containing in a external drag in FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I've seen a lot of solutions but none of them seen to work. I've seen the documentation, I know the event catching must be inside of `drop`, but what should I use? I tried eventRender, eventReceive, but I think the problem is that I don't know how to work with the data, and how to get it.

***UPDATE***

```
drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui){
    var data = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var hora = date.format("HH:mm:ss");
    var fim = date.add(1, "h").format("HH:mm:ss");
},
```

This is the code I have, but how can I get the title of the one I dropped? The code above works, I get the data correctly but how about the title?

Comment: Please post an example including code that you've at least attempted to make work.

Comment: @Difster Check the update

Answer (score 0):

Found it somehow. I searched a little bit more and got this code working, if anyone explain me why the code bellow works, I would be thankfull.

```
var titulo  = $.trim($(this).html());
```

Comment: Here, **[this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/drop/)** is the DOM element that has been dropped. **[html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** will return the contents of that element, and trim removes leading & trailing whitespace

Comment: @smcd Thanks for the explanation! I understood it completely!